# Can I ask for resource recommendations here?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, site-rec, resource-questions

I wish to ask what are the good resources to understand Python source code written in C language. Like there a book for Ruby i.e. Ruby under a microscope. It deals with low level implementation of Ruby.

I wish to ask same resource for Python. Can I ask this kind of programming language related questions here?

If not what community would fit well for these questions? (Surely not StackOverflow)

Comment: With the addition of some tags, the related questions posts on the side are a bit more relevant. You can read quite a bit about the history of such questions there (remember that advice from 2012 may not be completely applicable anymore).

Comment: [Why are questions asking for resources about conceptual problems that age well off-topic?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9561/192731)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resource requests are explicitly [off-topic per the help center](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> **and it is not about...**
>
> - where to find a software library, tool, book, research paper, blog, forum, or other resources

Related reading: [Why was my question closed as "Off Topic - Requests for Recommendations?"](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6487/)

---

The meta post goes into more detail explaining *why* this is the case. Some of the important points summarized below:

- Stack Exchange is *timeless*. A question should be mostly valid years from now. In the context of Programmers, fundamental design and programming concepts change at a glacial pace. Sure, specific technology comes and goes, but those of us in the computer science and software engineering fields for a decade or longer know that some hot new technology comes up every day, but by and large, the fundamentals that underpin our career field really do not change day to day. The lessons in [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131177052) are as applicable today as they were in 2004 when [Michael Feathers](https://michaelfeathers.silvrback.com/) wrote the book because he focuses on techniques and high-level concepts. Only the details about specific libraries and tools have changed over time.

  This puts the following points into the proper context:
- Resource requests are asking for specific resources that are relevant to the broader concepts. Links to tutorials and blogs can stagnate: if you want a Python tutorial for the particular concept you are trying to learn, it can grow out of date. Could you imagine stumbling across your question years later when Python 6 is all the rage, and ye olde Python 3 code is considered legacy technology that programmers grumble about maintaining just like we do with COBOL today? This is the core reason why this site focuses on *conceptual* problems that age well.
- Stack Exchange is designed to be a place where people can get answers for their questions, not as a thinly-veiled search engine where questions are answered with links to outside resources. We have Google for that.
- Answers are encouraged to link to outside resources, but an answer must stand on its own. Links can vanish or move. Then a link-only answer is useless, even if it is voted up to +100. Note that I opened this answer with two links, but provided a bit of explanation. This is regardless of the fact those links should never vanish unless this answer does as well (i.e. someone made Programmers.SE go away).

  From the [help center](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer):

  > Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context
  >   around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is
  >   and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an
  >   important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes
  >   permanently offline.

Thomas mentioned Stack Exchange's two resource recommendation sites, for software and hardware. Those are special: such questions are on-topic there. However, requesting links to blogs, tutorials, etc. are off-topic at both. Both sites have *very* strict requirements for what constitutes an on-topic question. As always, view a site's help center and poke around its meta (like you did here) for a bit before asking just to be sure. It makes for a better experience for everyone involved, and helps keep the signal to noise ratio high.

Comment: Nice explanation this would hold for ever as it stands alone :)

Comment: [Why are questions asking for resources about conceptual problems that age well off-topic?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9561/192731)

Answer (score 6):

No, these questions are off-topic here.

Very few communities take requests for resources. Two notable exceptions are Hardware Recommendations and Software Recommendations, both of which have strict rules about formulating the requirements for the recommendation.

Comment: For the specific things the OP asked (tutorials) unfortunately there is no dedicated stackexchange, although for example on physics one can ask for physics books (they allow good/bad lists in this regard but require community wiki then).

Comment: Are the votes in here the proof of consensus? Is there any threshold? For example I would call a 1-vote answer a consensus of the community

Comment: @Ooker Not just the votes. You need to consider the number of answers (2), the fact that no answer dissents (no one is proposing that resource recommendations should be allowed), and both answers suggesting that they are off-topic are positively scored. I don't think there's a more recent post that supersedes this one, so this stands as community consensus. But these things are fluid - someone could, at any time, bring up this matter and attempt to convince the community that resource requests should be allowed. It just hasn't happened yet.

Comment: @Ooker: I would not take this meta-question and its answers as a proof of consensus, too.  However, as a long-time member of this community, I can assure you that a large part of our community here regularly votes to close any resource request question, and almost noone votes to reopen. I have not see many close-reopen battles on this over the years. That is something you can take as a proof of consensus.